# Скрывающиеся блоки с помощью jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Добрый вечер!
Исходные данные: каталог товаров, каждый товар которого на странице отображается друг под другом.
Проблема в следующем: Необходимо чтобы товары выводились в виде списка и какой-нибудь метки "+" (например "Товар для Дома 1, [+] "), при нажатии на которую раскрывался блок с информацией конкретного товара. Также необходимо чтобы была функция "скрыть все блоки" и "раскрыть все блоки".

Буду благодарен, если подскажете в какую сторону копать (jqueryui перекопал, но не разобрался) или кинете линк на уже реализованный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.showinfo').click(function() { // при клике на .showinfo скрываем/раскрываем блок с инфой
  $(this).parent().find('.productinfo').toggle();
  $(this).text($(this).text()=='показать' ? 'скрыть' : 'показать');
  return false;
  });
$('#hide-all').click(function() { // при клике на #hide-all скрываем все блоки, меняем тексты кнопок
  $('.productinfo').hide('slow');
  $('.showinfo').text('показать');
  return false;
  });
$('#show-all').click(function() { // при клике на #show-all раскрываем все блоки, меняем тексты кнопок
  $('.productinfo').show('slow');
  $('.showinfo').text('скрыть');
  return false;
  });
});
</script>

<a href="#" id="hide-all">Скрыть все</a> 
<a href="#" id="show-all">Раскрыть все</a>

<div id="product-15" class="product">
  <!-- код -->
  <div class="productinfo" style="display: none;">текст с описание продукта</div>
  <a href="#" class="showinfo">показать</a>
</div>
```

Примерно так, могут быть ошибки, но суть вроде донес.

Comment: Спасибо!
Попробовал на тестовом примере на локальной машине - работает.
Как только залил на боевой сайт, так возникла следующая ошибка.
При загрузке страницы, текст у ссылки <a href="#" class="showinfo">показать</a> вместо слова "показать" появляется "????????". При нажатии на данную ссылку и на ссылки "Скрыть все" и "Раскрыть все" текст становится нормальным (т.е. "скрыть" или "показать"). Как это можно поправить?

Comment: У вас проблема с кодировками. Советую поставить везде utf-8 и сайт сохранить в ней же. Тут много на эту тему обсуждалось, [пример](http://hashcode.ru/questions/28140/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D1%83).

Похоже, что кодировка скрипта верная, а html - нет

Comment: Спасибо Вам за быстрый ответ! Я как раз только что поменял кодировку. Везде была ANSI as UTF-8, а в файле где использовал Ваш html код UTF-8. Поменял и всё заработало.

Answer (score 1):

пусть будет у каждого элемента списка скрытый блок с  инфой. примерная структура ( пусть список это набор блоков следующий друг за другом) 
пример одного.

```
  <div class="list goods_house">
    <span class="show">+</span>
    // инфв
    <div class "description">
      // тут скрытая инфа
    </div>
  </div>
```

css

```
 .description {
  display:none; 
  cursor:pointer;
 }
```

javascript

```
$(".show").bind("click", function(){
    var list = $(this).parent();
    var des  = list.children(".description").show();
});
```

ну и зависимоть это jquery и собственно функцию открывания закрывания осталость доделать(в этом варианте только откроется но не закроется описание) ну и со всем списком сделать по аналогии только ко всем .description